# Parse dataframe from R to Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api, rserve

I have been using both R and Tableau for analysis and visualization respectively.

I managed to connect the two using the RServe package. Trouble is that i create a data frame in R (outcome of my analysis) which i save as a csv file and then import it to Tableau.

Is there a way to import the data frame (and data) directly to Tableau?

Comment: This is really a request for us to do searching for package recommendations. OT on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Pro (and Public, too) can read .Rdata files directly (see https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/examples_statfile.htm). With the `save`function in R you can save the required data frame.